# How can I make a bot that bans the user that dm's it?

Tags: discord.py

```js
import discord

class client(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
         await ctx.guild.ban(message.author, reason="dm'ed honey le pot")
client = client()
client.run("mytoken")
client.run
```

I know that `ctx.guild.ban`, I can't do since `on_message` does not pass `ctx`, but how do I specify in which server to ban?

Comment: Is your bot a one server bot or a multiple server bot?

Comment: it's one server right now, I could just do a simple for loop.

Comment: I see. You need to first get the member and then the server it is in.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to choose a guild by its `id`. If the message is a DM, there is no guild to be referenced.

**EDIT**

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if not message.guild: # Replace 'guild_id' with the guild id you want
        self.fetch_guild(guild_id).ban(message.author, reason="dm'ed honey le pot")
```

Comment: it's just one server for the time being